# Bootstrap solution for flex 0 0

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I want my H2 text (child element), which is wrapped, have a nice border that suites the width of the wrapped text.

Almost getting there using the correct **bootstrap** classes, however when I give my H2 the class "flex-grow-0" it doesn't work. If I use the inline style "flex: 0 0;", it does exactly do what I want. See snippet. I really want to avoid creating classes myself. Thank you!

```css
:root {
 /* Change colors here to affect the whole site + change manually the colors in the .gradient tag + navigation etc */
    --color1:#F39207; /* Oranje */
    --color2:#951B81; /* Paars */
    --color3:#ffffff; /* White */
 --color4:#e6e6e6; /* grey */ 
}

/* GRID
------------------------------------------------------ */

.grid article div div {
 height:20em;
}

.grid article div div {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.grid article div div figure div {
 position: absolute; 
 top: 0; 
 left: 0;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 
 -webkit-transition: all 1.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s;
    -o-transition: all 1.5s;
    transition: all 1.5s;
}

.grid article div div figure div:hover {
 -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
 transform: scale(1.2);
 
}

/* GRID - Text */
.grid figcaption {
 z-index: 2;
}

.grid figcaption .grid-title-band {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: var(--color3);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.3em;
 border:0.4em solid var(--color3); 
 
 clip-path: polygon( 
    calc(0% + 5px) calc(0% + 5px), /* top left */
    calc(100% - 5px) calc(0% + 5px), /* top right */
    calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 5px), /* bottom right */
    calc(0% + 5px) calc(100% - 5px) /* bottom left */
 );
 transition: clip-path 0.4s linear;
}

.grid figcaption:hover .grid-title-band {
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<section class="grid">
 <article class="row bg-white pt-2 pb-2">
  <!-- Item // NOT GOOD -->
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
   <div>
    <a href="" class="text-decoration-none">
    <figure class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center p-5">
     <div class="w-100" style="background-image:url(http://www.cactusfestival.be/test-2/pics/bands/het_zesde_metaal.jpg);"></div>
     <figcaption class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around"><h2 class="flex-grow-0 grid-title-band p-3 m-0">This Example Is Wrong - Original</h2></figcaption>
    </figure>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- / Item -->
    <!-- Item // NOT GOOD -->
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
   <div>
    <a href="" class="text-decoration-none">
    <figure class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center p-5">
     <div class="w-100" style="background-image:url(http://www.cactusfestival.be/test-2/pics/bands/het_zesde_metaal.jpg);"></div>
     <figcaption class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around"><h2 class="flex-shrink-0 flex-grow-0 grid-title-band p-3 m-0">This Example Is Wrong - Edits</h2></figcaption>
    </figure>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- / Item -->
    <!-- Item // GOOD -->
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
   <div>
    <a href="" class="text-decoration-none">
    <figure class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center p-5">
     <div class="w-100" style="background-image:url(http://www.cactusfestival.be/test-2/pics/bands/het_zesde_metaal.jpg);"></div>
     <figcaption class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around"><h2 class="grid-title-band p-3 m-0" style="flex:0 0;">This Example Is Good</h2></figcaption>
    </figure>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- / Item -->
 </article>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because `flex-grow:0` is not the same as `flex: 0 0 0`. You need to set the `flex-basis` to `0` otherwise it defaults to `auto`.

Comment: You mean in the H2 class:flex-grow-0 flex-basis-0 ..."? I adjusted this in the snippet however it doesn't work. Or do you mean somewhere else? I'm a newbe, can you elaborate? Tnx

Comment: there is no flex-basis, you need to use flex-shrink-0 and flex-grow-0

Comment: Tried flex-shrink-0 and flex-grow-0 before (see snippet), did not work :(

Comment: It does seem that there is no utility class for `flex-basis: 0` but that is the solution AFAICT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider `.col` (where there is `flex-basis:0`) combined with `flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0`

```css
:root {
 /* Change colors here to affect the whole site + change manually the colors in the .gradient tag + navigation etc */
    --color1:#F39207; /* Oranje */
    --color2:#951B81; /* Paars */
    --color3:#ffffff; /* White */
 --color4:#e6e6e6; /* grey */ 
}

/* GRID
------------------------------------------------------ */

.grid article div div {
 height:20em;
}

.grid article div div {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.grid article div div figure div {
 position: absolute; 
 top: 0; 
 left: 0;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 
 -webkit-transition: all 1.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s;
    -o-transition: all 1.5s;
    transition: all 1.5s;
}

.grid article div div figure div:hover {
 -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
 transform: scale(1.2);
 
}

/* GRID - Text */
.grid figcaption {
 z-index: 2;
}

.grid figcaption .grid-title-band {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: var(--color3);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.3em;
 border:0.4em solid var(--color3); 
 
 clip-path: polygon( 
    calc(0% + 5px) calc(0% + 5px), /* top left */
    calc(100% - 5px) calc(0% + 5px), /* top right */
    calc(100% - 5px) calc(100% - 5px), /* bottom right */
    calc(0% + 5px) calc(100% - 5px) /* bottom left */
 );
 transition: clip-path 0.4s linear;
}

.grid figcaption:hover .grid-title-band {
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<section class="grid">
 <article class="row bg-white pt-2 pb-2">
  <!-- Item // NOT GOOD -->
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
   <div>
    <a href="" class="text-decoration-none">
    <figure class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center p-5">
     <div class="w-100" style="background-image:url(http://www.cactusfestival.be/test-2/pics/bands/het_zesde_metaal.jpg);"></div>
     <figcaption class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around"><h2 class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 col wid grid-title-band p-3 m-0">This Example Is Good</h2></figcaption>
    </figure>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- / Item -->
    <!-- Item // GOOD -->
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
   <div>
    <a href="" class="text-decoration-none">
    <figure class="d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center p-5">
     <div class="w-100" style="background-image:url(http://www.cactusfestival.be/test-2/pics/bands/het_zesde_metaal.jpg);"></div>
     <figcaption class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around"><h2 class="grid-title-band p-3 m-0" style="flex:0 0;">This Example Is Good</h2></figcaption>
    </figure>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- / Item -->
 </article>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```